# Excel - Sum between dates according to criteria and user input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need help figuring out how do I sum all the values inside a certain criteria and a user input date. Assuming that the criteria is 115 how do I add to the function the capabilty to sum according to a date range of choice?

I can get the criteria sum just fine with `=SUMIFS(B2:B21;C2:C21;"115")` but i cant figure out something to add the date to this function.

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTyf.jpg)

Any help is aprecciated! Thanks in advance!

*JonhDoe*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;C:C;"115";A:A;">=" & E3;A:A;"<=" & E5)
```

---

***NOTE***

This assumes that the "Dates" in column A are in fact true dates and not strings that look like dates.  It appears that your "numbers" are stored as text.

Comment: SUMIF/SUMIFS and COUNTIF/COUNTIFS do not distinguish between `"115"` and `115` either in the worksheet column or in the formula. You can mix-and-match.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes I was using that as to why I added the note about the dates.   I am worried that because the numbers are text strings the dates may also be such.  And therefore the formula will not work with dates that look like strings.

Comment: Ah! I see the light. Good note. Especially so with the left-aligned dates.